# Append Changes comment box: worflow unable to send the content of the box

Tags: designer-workflow, append-changes

I have one list with one 'comment' box with append changes (store multiple additions to the comment box). I have a simple workflow that sends an email to the author with the content of the comment box. Comment box is set to plain text.

I have tried in the SP designer workflow to add the current item > field > both 'as string' and as 'plain text' and they both shows up as empty.

Is there a way to send the actual comments/latest comment (I am ok with any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to allow the workflow to send the comments is to untick the box in the settings of the workflow called Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name